# Review Queue filtering doesn't stick after clearing/resetting

Tags: bug, status-review, review-queues

The Close Vote Review Queue has had a problem since the last week of September 2023.

1. When clearing the filtering options in the close vote review queue, the queue does not fully update. The filter options will be saved (e.g. switching from showing "opinion based" only to all types), but the actual page content that shows the questions and vote/action buttons remains blank. I have to refresh the page to fix this issue.
2. Even after refreshing the page when encountering the issue above, after performing a review, the filtering will automatically revert back to my prior choice (e.g. showing "opinion based" only options). This is particularly frustrating when the reason I switched from one filter to all is because there were no more questions in the queue under the single filter I had been using. For example:

   [image: screenshot of review page with 'no more Opinion-based questions' message showing, but with the default/'all' filter options checked]

Even after refreshing/Ctrl+F5ing, the queue will occasionally revert back to the 'no more questions matching "opinion based"' message despite still being set to no filtering.

Comment: Given the deafening silence - does it still happen or was it a temporary glitch in the Matrix?

Comment: @Gimby Still happens.

Comment: it seems it happens only when the queue has no more items with the original filters

Comment: @blackgreen Yes, that's my experience as well.

Comment: Still happening nearly a month later. Clearly _something_ changed on the backend around that time... Should be fairly straightforward to look at the change logs and see what related to caching or session variables may have been adjusted in the code...

Comment: Still ongoing, and in fact it's worse than previously reported--*any* filtering by tag or choice is regularly forgotten or just straight-up ignored. Around the week of September 25th they pushed a change that broke review queues _badly_, and haven't seemed to look back since.